# error when trying to edit status of Order in admin interface(playframework)

Tags: java, hibernate, persistence, playframework, admin

In my app ,I have a class `Order` that contains a collection of `cartItem`s .The Order can have status `'pending' ,'confirmed'` etc.
After the customer placed the order,it has a status 'confirmed'.Since wrong payment info was provided  by customer,the admin decides to change the status of Order to 'pending'.Using the `CRUD/admin` interface ,I selected the Order entry and tried to edit the status field.This caused the following error.

```
        PersistenceException occured : org.hibernate.HibernateException:
 A collection with 
    cascade="all-delete-orphan" was no longer referenced
     by the owning entity instance: models.Order.cartItems
```

The error shown on page is :

```
In {module:crud}/app/controllers/CRUD.java (around line 100)
96:  } catch (TemplateNotFoundException e) {
97:     render("CRUD/show.html", type, object);
98:  }
99:    }
100:  object._save();//Here error marked in red
101: flash.success(Messages.get("crud.saved", type.modelName));
102:  if (params.get("_save") != null) {
103:    redirect(request.controller + ".list");
104:   }
105:    redirect(request.controller + ".show", object._key());
106:     }
```

The models in my app are;

```
@Entity
public class Order extends Model {
    @ManyToOne
    private Customer customer;

    @OneToMany( cascade=CascadeType.ALL,orphanRemoval=true)

    private Set<CartItem> cartItems;

    private String status;
    ...
}

@Entity
public class CartItem extends Model implements Comparable<CartItem>{

    @OneToOne
    private Product product;

    private int quantity;
...
}
```

I don't really understand why this happened.How can changing the value of a field cause this? What should I do to avoid this error? I need the admin to be able to edit this field..

If anyone can suggest a solution,it would be nice.

Comment: Why are all of your model attributes private? Have you implemented your own getters and setters? Is there anything out of the ordinary in them?

Comment: no nothing special..I just created them private and generated getters/setters using eclipse ide.

Comment: There is no need to do this considering Play does this for you.  Only override the get/set if you need custom code.

Answer (score 0):

What about setting `mappedBy` in the `Order` class and adding `@ManyToOne` to the `CartItem`?

```
@Entity
public class Order extends Model {
    @ManyToOne
    private Customer customer;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy="order",cascade=CascadeType.ALL,orphanRemoval=true)
    private Set<CartItem> cartItems;

    private String status;
    ...
}

@Entity
public class CartItem extends Model implements Comparable<CartItem> {

    @OneToOne
    private Product product;

    @ManyToOne
    private Order order;

    private int quantity;
...
}
```